# JQuery cookie set in other Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I had a javascript Function showHide(shID) , which is a function to hide div or show content after clicked "read more" . Here is my Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Garfrey/5xf72j4m/8/

As you see when user click on it and show more content , but I just need to hide once , means when the user come back to visit my page and the hidden content is still showing. So that I need to add JQuery cookie , but what I wrote was wrong and it's not working .I'am new in Javascript . Do anyone know how to fix it ? thanks in advance , I really need help .

here my code for function :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   if($.cookie("example")=='1') {
      function showHide(shID) {
      if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none') {
         document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
      }
      else {
         document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'inline';
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
      }
   }
   } else {

        $.cookie("example", "1");
    }                 
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't define a function inside jQuery's ready function without doing something like this

```js
var showHide;
$(function() { // Document ready
  showHide = function(sh) {
    //Insert function code here
  };
});
```

I think in your case you might be better off defining the function outside of the ready function then binding it to the button's onclick handler dynamically.

I also added a data-showhide attribute to the button to pass the variable into the showhide function onclick.

```js
function showHide() {
  var shID = $(this).data("showhide"); // Use lower case only in data
  if (document.getElementById(shID + '-show').style.display != 'none') {
    document.getElementById(shID + '-show').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById(shID + '-show').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
  }
}

$(function() {
  $("#example-show").on("click", showHide);
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" data-showhide="example">
```

The cookies can be set to specific values in the showHide function. The ready handler can then query the cookie and determine whether or not to show or hide the div.
This fiddle shows this in action http://jsfiddle.net/e52hxosb/19/

Comment: HI wnbates , really thanks for your reply and your help ! Your code is working , but I just not sure the way I input my cookie function is correct or not . Can you help me to review ? really appreciate =D  here is my Fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/Garfrey/e52hxosb/15/

Comment: In order to use $.cookie() you need to add the jquery cookie plugins script as an external resouce. A cdn version can be found here https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js
Your fiddle shows you overwriting the showHide function with a new function inside the ready handler. You don't need to overwrite showHide, just use the if statement and $.cookie to decide if you want to call showHide.

Comment: base on your comment I had call out the jquery cookie plugins script from cdn ,inside my html path . Secondly , I deleted overwrite showHide and set up the cookie function . Here are my fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/Garfrey/e52hxosb/16/ .... Is my code correct ? =D

Comment: Getting there. I'm a bit confused about what you want the cookie to do.

Comment: I need this cookie function to set into this hide/show function , just need to hide the content for once .So that when the user come back to visit my page ,they are no longer to click the button again and already showing the content

Comment: I've updated the answer with a new fiddle which shows how this could work with cookies.

Comment: Sorry to keep disturb on you , but I really need your help ... I found your code was almost there . The hide function was gone  .. it's seem like the cookie function blocking the hide function , can hide function come first and click on button to show the content ?